# Is it possible for a SQL query to join after paginating?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query like the following that I used to retrieve a business and all its contacts.

```
SELECT  *
FROM Business as business
    JOIN Contact as contact
        ON contact.BusinessEntityId = business.Id
WHERE business.Id = '12345'
```

Now I want to do something like the following:

```
SELECT  *
FROM Business as business
    JOIN Contact as contact
        ON contact.BusinessEntityId = business.Id
WHERE business.State = 'TX'
ORDER BY business.Id
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
```

The problem is that the pagination occurs on the rows returned from the whole query, which means I may get partial results for the contacts of the last business on a page. What I want is to paginate the results from the WHERE and then JOIN those results with the contacts. This way I can display all the contact information for every business on the page.

Is there any way to do this without executing a separate query to get contacts for each business?

Comment: You can put the `offset` in a subquery.  I'm not sure that you'll get a particular advantage in performance, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think temp tables is the simplest way to go here.

```
SELECT  *
INTO #temp
FROM Business as business
WHERE business.State = 'TX'
ORDER BY business.Id
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY


SELECT *
FROM #temp as business
JOIN Contact as contact
   ON contact.BusinessEntityId = business.Id
```

This should also make it run pretty fast, since the join will only happen over 20 records. This is also assuming that you have only one contact per business, otherwise you will get more that 20 records on the second join and you will have to run a OFFSET/FETCH there too.

Comment: I think this is what this is all about; there are sometimes multiple contacts per business ID and the OP wants to make sure to only get complete contact sets. You have provided a good solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This would be done with a `WITH TIES` clause, but SQL Server doesn't support it:

```
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS WITH TIES;
```

But you can do your pagination yourself with `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT b.*, c.*, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY b.id) AS rn
  FROM business b
  JOIN contact c ON c.businessentityid = b.id
  WHERE b.state = 'TX'
) ranked
WHERE rn BETWEEN 101 AND 120;
```

This skips the first 100 IDs and gives you the next 20, no matter how many rows per ID.

Comment: This makes sense but I can't get it to work, I get a syntax error on the final WHERE: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. Expecting AS, ID or QUOTED ID. I don't think rn is accessible there?

Comment: Got it to work. First seems to require an AS after the outer FROM. Second, there are duplicate columns in my tables so I had to alias them.

Comment: Because of the need to alias columns this is a but harder to use but it seems to perform slightly better. Anyone have comments on the performance of this approach vs the nested select?

Comment: Sorry for the missing alias for the derived table (aka subquery). As to performance: I don't know. It doesn't seem fast to me, but pagination never is. In the given example the DBMS will have to find the top 120 IDs to get those final 20. It may use some sophisticated approach for this, but it may as well just sort and rank every single row in the table. And it will do so every time you call the query with the next range. If you need speed, you may have to create an indexed column (or separate table) for this and evaluate the page groups once before you start page-reading the table.

Answer (score 0):

Alex's answer did almost exactly what I needed. Thank you Alex, that gave me what I needed to arrive at the final solution. I've marked your post as the solution but I think anyone reading this in the future will want to use the final solution as it returns the exact results I needed, its simpler, and it performs much better. So, here it is.

Note: I had not seen Thorsten post when I wrote this.

To get the correct results using a temp table I had to use a `LEFT JOIN` because some businesses did not have a contact. Using just the `JOIN` resulted in missing business records. Also, probably should drop the table at the end. This is the working version of the above query.

```
SELECT * INTO #temp
FROM Business AS business
WHERE business.State = 'TX'
ORDER BY business.Id
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY

SELECT *
FROM #temp AS business
LEFT JOIN Contact AS contact ON contact.Id = business.Id

DROP TABLE #temp
```

This works but performed pretty poorly. After a bit of research I realized this can be done with a nested query. This is the modified query that I'm going with.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT *
   FROM Business AS business
   WHERE business.State = 'TX'
   ORDER BY business.Id
   OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY) AS business
LEFT JOIN Contact AS contact ON contact.Id = business.Id
```